Maximum volume of swept cylinder in cone using Pappu's theorem relating to known center of gravity position
A cylinder is inscribed in a right circular cone of common horizontal base plane OC.
It is known/given that the center of gravity of swept/ revolved triangle is situated at one third altitude on a median as shown. It is required to find the radius,height point B on the slant generator VB to obtain maximum swept volume of the cylinder, without using calculus for finding an extremum.
Is it correct to argue based on Pappu's theorem that in order to obtain maximum volume of the swept cylinder, the  cylinder height plane must coincide with the line AGB through center of gravity of the cross section triangle ?
It does not appear to be so directly, but am unable to find the missing link in the argument.
Thanks for all associated thoughts/comments.

